# C# : openfiledialog filtering issue

Tags: c#, .net, file, filter, openfiledialog

i am writing a code when a user click open file , i would like to filter the type of files to .txt only so i did the following code , but it didnt work it didnt show any txt files at all , just an empty folder , here is the code :

```
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog o = new OpenFileDialog();
            o.Filter = "Text File | .txt";
            o.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
            o.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch
        {}
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding an empty `catch` block as well.  You probably wouldn't want to swallow the exception.

Comment: yeah you are right , i shouldn`t probably do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will only show files named `.txt`, i.e., a single space (which it might ignore?) followed by a dot and "txt".

Remove the spaces around the `|`, and add a wildcard so you match more than one file.

```
o.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
```

Comment: Wow , thank you very much , i really hate when i miss something small like that glad stackoverflow and you guys are here for me and people like me :D

Answer (score 3):

You need a wildcard for the filter, like this:

```
 o.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
```